# How to read Json data in android

Tags: android, json

I have a raw data as in a below format:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "abc",
    "type": "consumer"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "cdf",
    "type": "consumer"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "jok",
    "type": "owner"
  }
]
```

Please let me know how can I covert that into `JsonArray` and get the each values.

Comment: it was asked almost 100500 times before

Comment: Searching the forums would be easier than answering new question !

Comment: create a dummy project and as it is copy and paste the code or else just download the code from there and analyse it on your own ....i am sure you will get this within 40minuts..
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: you need to know how to parse the json?

Comment: where is the raw data on the server??

Comment: Its not on the server. Its in my java file itself

Comment: @brig what? you can store the json in assests folder as myfile.json. you can then parse the json. post your java code if you say its in your java code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest way to parse your `JSON` String. I would suggest your to read `JSON` documents.

But, here is a sample code.

```
try {
        String jsonString = new String("[{\"id\": \"1\",\"name\": \"abc\",\"type\": \"consumer\"}]");
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        for(int index = 0;index < jsonArray.length(); index++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(index);
            String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
            String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
            String type = jsonObject.getString("type");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You can also parse using GSON https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/